# Consolidate FirstName/LastName into FullName ASP.NET Core Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm using EF Core code-first models in ASP.NET Core 2.0.

In an attempt to simplify models, I have tried to consolidate the `FirstName` and `LastName` fields of the `ApplicationUser` model:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int>
...
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
...
```

to

```
...
public string FullName { get; set; }
...
```

However, when I supply seed data:

```
...
FullName = "Test McTesterson"
```

SQL server only saves the last name.

My assumption is that there is some sort of attribute that I can decorate my field with to include both names in the string?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want a field called `FullName` to exist in the Database?  Or do you just want to view the concatenation of those two strings on the client (aka your code)?

Comment: just create a persisted computed column

Comment: What would you expect to happen if you set the full name to `Bob Andrew Smith`? There's a good reason first name and surname are distinct properties

Comment: It sounds like this should be a computer field in the object that returns a formatted string with first name and last name.

Comment: @maccettura Yes, I want field called FullName in the database.

Comment: Why have such a field in the database? What purpose would that serve?

Comment: @JuanR just to simplify. But it may not be direction I should go. Would it be better practice to store separate fields in the database?

Comment: @Joe I would suggest keeping them separate in the database, and have a read only, non-database field that concatenates them on your client, like `public string FullName => $"{FirstName} {LastName}";`

Comment: You are not simplifying anything. Rather, you will add [future] complexity when you have to deal with weird names, as someone else suggested. Check out my answer below for an alternative that simplifies model usage.

Answer (score 2):

If the goal is to simplify **usage** of the model, I would recommend implementing a computed field instead:

```
public string FullName 
{ 
    get { return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName); }
}
```

If you want to get fancier, you can add a method to allow for formatting:

```
public string GetFullName(string format)
{
    return string.Format(format, FirstName, LastName);
}
```

Sample usage:

```
var name = user.GetFullName("{0} {1}"); //returns John Doe
var name2 = user.GetFullName("{1}, {0}"); //returns Doe, John
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, a computed field is the way to go. However, the cleanest solution for me is to use string interpolation with an expression body:

```
public string FullName => $"{FirstName} {LastName}";
```